# How do I finish this wall repair around the outlet?

Tags: drywall, receptacle

I had to put a piece of drywall to cover up the hole that was created when we installed a 14-50 outlet.

How do I finish this to make it look okay? (Note: this is an interior wall)

[image: before drywall]
[image: after drywall]

Comment: Is your drywall patch backwards?

Comment: Is that an outside wall?

Comment: That’s an interior wall.

Comment: The other side of the drywall has green paper. Do I need to flip it? It is crucial?

Comment: "All" (I'm sure there are exceptions...) drywall has brown paper on the back. White is the usual front, green is for moisture/mold resistant. The green color itself isn't magical, but that means if you put the white or green facing the area to be finished you can instantly see what you've got (until it is painted/etc., of course). In any case, that green paper (or even the usual white paper) has different properties from the brown "junk back paper".

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact So, should I cut out another piece and make sure the green side is facing out?

Comment: Yes, that is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

First, sand or scrape off enough surrounding texture so that you can apply tape to the seams.

Next, you need to get the proper texture sponge (knockdown, orange peel, etc...) and just try your best with a watery mud. Take your time to feather out past the edges. Heck, you might find that going out 2-3 feet produces the most seamless result.

If you think the result is turning out poorly then wash off your attempt before it dries. You can always wash drywall mud after it dries but it requires a little more effort.

See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7oacSmLB2A

---

Also, your drywall patch piece is backwards.

> Yes, each manufacturer designs drywall to have a front and rear. One side is for finishing, and the other goes against the studs. The rear can have special coatings for different moisture level protection.
>
> If you accidentally installed the drywall backward. We recommend you remove it and install it correctly. If it is not clear which side is which, you should confirm with the manufacturer.

[Source](https://natureofhome.com/which-side-of-drywall-faces-out/)

Comment: Should I use paper tape or mesh tape?

Comment: @milesmeow I don't have enough experience with either to make an educated suggestion. You can watch some YouTube videos on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

I will not address texture matching, hopefully you'll get that advice in other answers.  A few things I'll address:

1. That looks like an outside wall, and an interior outlet.  Hopefully it's in an enclosed or protected area not subject to wetness.
2. If you match the texture it looks like the outlet will be somewhat recessed in it.  And some 14-50 cords won't be able to insert properly.  You should add a mud ring or small box extender that will bring the outlet face proud of the stucco surface.
3. If you find it too hard to (learn to) match textures, cover the patch with some contrasting material (paint, siding, paneling) that looks intentional and bridge the seams with vinyl or metal strips.